# Time picker (Open Source)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm giving a try on a open source time picker of jQuery library ([ptTimeSelect](http://pttimeselect.sourceforge.net/example/index.html)). I have placed the code in the header of my php file but once I click on the field to show time, it doesn't appear.

Header to call out:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ptTimeSelect.js"></script>
<link href="css/jquery.ptTimeSelect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

$('#Time').ptTimeSelect({
popupImage: 'Select Time'
});
```

Updated Body Code:

```
<input name="Time" id="Time" class="jquery.ptTimeSelect"/>
```

It does show the time now. but the pattern is distorted.

Or anyone can advise if there is any good open source for time picker only.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the onclick event, just use it like this:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#time').ptTimeSelect({
    popupImage: 'Select Time'
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<input name="Time" id="time" />
```

Didn't used the plugin though, hope I helped anyway.

Comment: it helps and there's popup. But it doesnt show the nice style of the time. Any idea why? I have added my css.

Comment: Try it without the popupImage parameter, like: $('#time').ptTimeSelect(); This should call the default design.

Comment: it's still the same. Design distorted.

Comment: Well, if everything's linked correctly, and the images are at the right place, then I can't really see what's the problem. :/

Comment: the CSS does not have any images link. Is this the problem ? As I did not see any source code on images background urls.

Comment: Download the full package, there's the images folder.
http://sourceforge.net/project/platformdownload.php?group_id=190063